# k8s access control to single pod

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I am trying to set access control for using the "shell" UI button on the deploy dashboard, and only need this for one single pod. By using the k8s RBAC auth model, I need something like this and binding to a role:

```html
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  resourceNames: [“api-server-f5b95446b-58wz4”]
  verbs: ["create"]
```

However, the postfix "-f5b95446b-58wz4" is randomly generated during deploy time, and it will change constantly. So this solution won't work.

If the resourceNames could support wild card string then it will resolve my issue, but looks like it is a known gap and not supported ATM (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/56582)

Anyone idea if there is better way that I can achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a webhook might help in this situation as the requirement is currently not present

Answer (score 1):

You can use a policy engine like Kyverno to control what can/cannot. Example, prevent exec into to a specific pod filter by name like [this](https://kyverno.io/policies/other/block-pod-exec-by-pod-and-container/).